# scheduling code is not identifying all solutions. possibly not backtracking?

Tags: prolog

I have a scheduling problem where I want to ensure that all customers get one of three slots. There are exactly three slots that can be filled. Here is my code so far.

```
get_taken_times(Schedule, Times):-
get_taken_times(Schedule, [], Times).
get_taken_times([], Times, Times).    
get_taken_times([C-T|CustomerTimes], TimeAccum, Times) :- 
    get_taken_times(CustomerTimes, [T | TimeAccum], Times).  


schedule(Customers, Schedule):-
schedule(Customers, PartialSchedule, Schedule).
schedule([], Schedule, Schedule).
schedule([Customer-[Time|Times]|CustomerTimes], PartialSchedule, Schedule):- 
(   get_taken_times(PartialSchedule, TakenTimes),
    \+ member(Time, TakenTimes)) -> 
        schedule(CustomerTimes, [Customer-Time | PartialSchedule], Schedule);
schedule([Customer-Times|CustomerTimes], PartialSchedule, Schedule).
```

If this is run as a test

```
schedule([a-[1,2,3], b-[1,2,3], c-[1,2,3]], Schedule)
```

I get this result, which is fine

```
[c-3,b-2,a-1]
```

But I do not understand why the other five possible solutions (there should be six total) are not being found. Presumably there is some issue with the backtracking but I do not understand where? Could someone please explain how this might be modified to find all six solutions?

Comment: Are you really calling it with variables `C`, `B`, and `A` like that? (Those are variables, since they start with a capital letter.) By the way, your code has two singletons: `C` line 4 and `PartialSchedule` on line 9.

Comment: oh, yeah, those are typos, I was not calling them like that. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as noted in a comment as well, *always check singleton warnings*, and *always* fix them before trying anything else. Prolog systems don't emit these warnings for fun! They emit them because they often indicate serious errors in your program. In this particular case, if I leave in your singletons but otherwise apply my fix below, your program behaves like this:

```
?- schedule([a-[1,2,3], b-[1,2,3], c-[1,2,3]], Schedule).
Schedule = [c-3, b-2, a-1] ;
Schedule = [c-2, b-3, a-1] ;
Schedule = [c-3, b-1, a-2] ;
Schedule = [c-1, b-3, a-2] ;
Schedule = [c-2, b-1, a-3] ;
Schedule = [c-1, b-2, a-3] ;
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

Now, let's consider the backtracking issue. Besides a solution with `a-1` you also want to try solutions with `a-2` and `a-3`. But at the point where you consider the customer-time term `a-[1, 2, 3]`, you have `Customer = a`, `Time = 1`, `Times = [2, 3]`, and `TakenTimes = []`. `1` is not a member of `[]`. You only ever try alternative times if the currently considered `Time` is a member of `TakenTimes`, but as `TakenTimes` is `[]` and nothing is a member of it. So you will never try alternative times for `a`.

The problem is your manual recursion over the customer's available times. You are effectively implementing a kind of "optimization" where you only consider one solution, not all possible ones. To get all possible ones, you need to enumerate (not recurse on!) all of a customer's available times. Like this:

```
schedule([], Schedule, Schedule).
schedule([Customer-AvailableTimes|CustomerTimes], PartialSchedule, Schedule):- 
    get_taken_times(PartialSchedule, TakenTimes),
    member(Time, AvailableTimes),
    \+ member(Time, TakenTimes),
    schedule(CustomerTimes, [Customer-Time | PartialSchedule], Schedule).
```

For a given list of `TakenTimes`, this tries *all* legal alternative times for a customer. And, if you fix your singleton problems, this gives you all solutions and then terminates nicely:

```
?- schedule([a-[1,2,3], b-[1,2,3], c-[1,2,3]], Schedule).
Schedule = [c-3, b-2, a-1] ;
Schedule = [c-2, b-3, a-1] ;
Schedule = [c-3, b-1, a-2] ;
Schedule = [c-1, b-3, a-2] ;
Schedule = [c-2, b-1, a-3] ;
Schedule = [c-1, b-2, a-3] ;
false.
```

One more note on your implementation of `get_taken_times/2`: It's true that often you need an accumulator argument to do interesting stuff on lists. But here it's not needed at all, and your solution is not even as general as it could be:

```
?- get_taken_times(Xs, [1, 2, 3]).
Xs = [_2686-3, _2704-2, _2722-1] ;
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

Rather, when relating lists, where the list heads are in some relation, we usually express this in the clause head directly. Like this:

```
get_taken_times([], []).
get_taken_times([_Customer-Time | CustomerTimes], [Time | Times]) :-
    get_taken_times(CustomerTimes, Times).
```

This behaves more logically:

```
?- get_taken_times(Xs, [1, 2, 3]).
Xs = [_2046-1, _2058-2, _2070-3].
```

A better name for this predicate would be something like `pairs_seconds/2` or possibly `pairs_values/2`. It is present in the SWI-Prolog library under the latter name.